# U-boot 1.6.6 : I am trying to Edit the Source code to Enable PCI for MPC8640 Custom Board

Tags: embedded-linux

I have gone through the Source Code . The CONFIG_PCI is defined in the u-boot/include/configs/MPC8641HPCN.h file [General]. This MACRO has been Enabled in the .h file which says if i compile the configuration for this board the PCI will be Enumerated and will find out the devces Located on the Bus.
Using the Functions Defined : cmd_pci.c : u-boot/common/cmd_pci.c

```
void pci_header_show(pci_dev_t dev);
void pci_header_show_brief(pci_dev_t dev);

void pciinfo(int BusNum, int ShortPCIListing)

PCI_BDF(BusNum, Device, Function);

pci_read_config_word(dev, PCI_VENDOR_ID, &VendorID);

pci_read_config_byte(dev, PCI_HEADER_TYPE, &HeaderType);
```

Now guys , I have stucked and Some concept..Memory mapping...I have DDR interfaced to the Processor..and Also not able to find which code points to the Memory Mapping in the Current U-boot.
Also if any body could just state the Flow of Enumeration functions..files and Memory mapping ..with few hints will be Beneficial..I have been going through some books "PCI system Architecture " but they are general and does not point to any topic specifying..how to Enumerate A PCI ..when MPC8640 Processor is acting as HOST.

Thanks And Regard's
Hrishikesh!

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot 1.6.6 doesn't exist. See the list of U-Boot releases at ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/u-boot/. If you're talking about 1.1.6, then that's a prehistoric release, and you will hardly get any sort of support from the open-source community if you stick with such an old version.